# Numerical solution of an advance-delay ODE with multiple advances and delays

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a differential equation of the form

```
a[x_] := x
b[x_] := x^2
c1[x_] := x
x1 = 1;
c2[x_] := x
x2 = 10;
c3[x_] := x
x3 = 5;
c4[x_] := x
x4 = 15;
eq = D[a[x] f'[x] + b[x] f[x], x] + (c1[x + x1] f[x + x1] - c1[x] f[x]) + (c2[x + x2] f[x + x2] - c2[x] f[x]) + (c3[x - x3] f[x - x3] - c3[x] f[x]) + (c4[x - x4] f[x - x4] - c4[x] f[x]) == 0;
```

with the boundary conditions at "infinity"

```
l = 100;
bc1 = f'[l] == 0;
bc2 = f[l] == 0;
```

Real coefficients are way to difficult and the number of advance-delay terms is larger, so this is just an example problem.

All coefficients `a`, `b`, `c1`, ..., `c4` are zero everywhere outside the integration region `[0, l]`. Moreover, we can assume that `f` is also 0 outside `[0, l]`.

I know that `NDSolve` handles delay and advance differential equations pretty well. But I can't figure out how to apply it for solving this system. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**

I should have mentioned that the unknown function `f[x]` satisfies the integral constraint

```
Integrate[Sqrt[x] f[x], {x, 0, l}] == 1
```

**Update**

I am updating the OP with some corrections to parameters and specific expressions for the system coefficients.

First, I have changed `xmin` and therefore the definition of `l`, so that the integration stops exactly at `x = 1`.

```
k0 =3;
M0 =8;
xmin = .025;
xmax = 100;
l = xmax;
x1 = 11.65;
```

Limiting the consideration by only `c1` term, I have obtained the coefficients of the real system as follows:

```
dAfFun[x_]:=Piecewise[{{1.4476805109594064` 10^-23+1.1735563659975857` 10^-24  x^(1.4),xmin<=x<=xmax}},0]
AfFun[x_]:=Piecewise[{{4.17425813460343` 10^-24+4.4423429301477025` 10^-23 x,xmin<=x<=xmax}},0]
Rx1Fun[x_]:=Piecewise[{{4.537932520459608` 10^-17/(1+1.3188535755423771`Exp[-0.07679009872276484`(x-x1)])-4.529403364443408`*^-17/(1+1.3148412969171435`Exp[-0.07683234639209759`(x-x1)]),x1<=x<=xmax}},0]
```

Thence,

```
a[x_] := dAfFun[x l]
b[x_] := AfFun[x l]
c1[x_] := Rx1Fun[x l]
```

As a result, `NSolve` and `FindRoot` find negative roots (the solution looks reasonable though), while `NMinimize` with `Method -> "RandomSearch"` runs for unreasonably long time.

The actual solution pretty much looks like `PDF[ChiDistribution[1], x]` plus effects from the `c1` term visible after `x1`. So, maybe instead of `EulerE`, we need to consider `PDF[ChiDistribution[k], x]`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to solve it with a single delay and single advance separately. But I am not able to combine them.

Comment: If coefficients `a, b, c1, ..., c4` are zero everywhere outside the integration region then why you define functions `a[x_] := x; b[x_] := x^2; c1[x_] := x; ...` which are not zero outside $(0, l)$?

Comment: With boundary conditions `bc1 = f'[l] == 0; bc2 = f[l] == 0`  solution is $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Regarding the coefficients, I meant to say that we can define, e.g., `a[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, 0<= x <= l}}, 0]`.

Regarding the boundary conditions, I do not get it why the solution must be trivial. Without advance and delay terms, i.e., the solution of `a[x] f'[x] + b[x] f[x] = 0` is a decreasing function of `x` like `PDF[ChiDistribution[1], x]` (not exactly equal, but the behavior is the same).

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan With additional constraint you added there is nonzero solution - see my answer.

Comment: Is equation for updated case has a form  `eq = D[a[x] f'[x] + b[x] f[x], 
   x] + (c1[x + x1] f[x + x1] - c1[x] f[x])==0`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan Please, see Update 2 to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved by colocation method with using Euler wavelets. First, we map solution on unit interval $0\le x\le 1$. Then we define function f, first (f1) and second (f2) derivative as follows

```
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 7; xmin = 0; xmax = 100; l = xmax - xmin; nn = 
 Total[With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
   Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]]; dx = 
 1/(nn); xl = Table[xmin + s*dx, {s, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[s - 1]] + xl[[s]])/2, {s, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Intx1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Intx2 = Integrate[Intx1, t1];
intx1[y_] := Intx1 /. t1 -> y; intx2[y_] := Intx2 /. t1 -> y; 
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y;

a[x_] := l Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}];
b[x_] := l^2 Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}];
c1[x_] := l Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}];
x1 = 1/l;
c2[x_] := l Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}];
x2 = 10/l;
c3[x_] := l Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}];
x3 = 5/l;
c4[x_] := l Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}];
x4 = 15/l;
(*eq=D[a[x] f'[x]+b[x] f[x],x]+(c1[x+x1] f[x+x1]-c1[x] \
f[x])+(c2[x+x2] f[x+x2]-c2[x] f[x])+(c3[x-x3] f[x-x3]-c3[x] \
f[x])+(c4[x-x4] f[x-x4]-c4[x] f[x])\[Equal]0;bc1=f'[l]\[Equal]0;
bc2=f[l]\[Equal]0;*)

var = Array[v, {nn}]; f[x_] := var . intx2[x] + x v1 + v0; 
f1[x_] := var . intx1[x] + v1; f2[x_] := var . Psi[x];
```

Finally we compute equation in collocation points and solve system of algebraic equations with `FindRoot`

```
eq = Table[
   a[x] f2[x]/l^2 + f1[x]/l + b[x] f1[x]/l + 
     2 l x f[x] + (c1[x + x1] f[x + x1] - 
       c1[x] f[x]) + (c2[x + x2] f[x + x2] - 
       c2[x] f[x]) + (c3[x - x3] f[x - x3] - 
       c3[x] f[x]) + (c4[x - x4] f[x - x4] - c4[x] f[x]) == 0, {x, 
    xcol}];

eqs = Join[
  Drop[eq, -1], {l^1.5 Sum[
      Sqrt[xcol[[i]]] f[xcol[[i]]] (xl[[i + 1]] - xl[[i]]), {i, 
       nn}] == 1, f[1] == 0, f1[1] == 0}]; varM = Join[var, {v0, v1}];

sol = FindRoot[eqs, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]]
```

Visualization `f[x]`

```
Plot[f[x/l] /. sol, {x, 0, l}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. We also can use `NMinimize` with bound `f[x]>0` at `0<x<l` as follows (note we define exact integral `intf[x]` instead of sum)

```
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 8; xmin = 0; xmax = 100; l = xmax - xmin; nn = 
 Total[With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
   Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]]; dx = 
 1/(nn); xl = Table[xmin + s*dx, {s, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[s - 1]] + xl[[s]])/2, {s, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Intx1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Intx2 = Integrate[Intx1, t1]; Intx3 = 
 Integrate[Intx2 Sqrt[t1], t1, Assumptions -> t1 > 0]; 
intx1[y_] := Intx1 /. t1 -> y; intx2[y_] := Intx2 /. t1 -> y; 
intx3[y_] := Intx3 /. t1 -> y; Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y;

 a[x_] := l Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}];
b[x_] := l^2 Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}];
c1[x_] := l Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}];
x1 = 1/l;
c2[x_] := l Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}];
x2 = 10/l;
c3[x_] := l Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}];
x3 = 5/l;
c4[x_] := l Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}];
x4 = 15/l;
(*eq=D[a[x] f'[x]+b[x] f[x],x]+(c1[x+x1] f[x+x1]-c1[x] \
f[x])+(c2[x+x2] f[x+x2]-c2[x] f[x])+(c3[x-x3] f[x-x3]-c3[x] \
f[x])+(c4[x-x4] f[x-x4]-c4[x] f[x])\[Equal]0;bc1=f'[l]\[Equal]0;
bc2=f[l]\[Equal]0;*)

var = Array[v, {nn}]; 
intf[x_] := var . intx3[x] + 2/5 v1 x^(5/2) + 2/3 v0 x^(3/2); 
f[x_] := var . intx2[x] + x v1 + v0; f1[x_] := var . intx1[x] + v1; 
f2[x_] := var . Psi[x];

eq = Table[
   a[x] f2[x]/l^2 + f1[x]/l + b[x] f1[x]/l + 
    2 l x f[x] + (c1[x + x1] f[x + x1] - 
      c1[x] f[x]) + (c2[x + x2] f[x + x2] - 
      c2[x] f[x]) + (c3[x - x3] f[x - x3] - 
      c3[x] f[x]) + (c4[x - x4] f[x - x4] - c4[x] f[x]), {x, xcol}];

 bc = 
 Join[{l^(3/2) intf[1] == 1, f[1] == 0, f1[1] == 0}, 
  Table[f[x] > 0, {x, xcol}]]; varM = Join[var, {v0, v1}]; 
solm = 
 NMinimize[{eq . eq, bc}, varM]
```

Visualization of solutions for nn=10, 16, 24, 28, 32, 56
[image: Figure 2]
We can combine all plots in one using `Show`
[image: Figure 3]

Update 2. We can use wavelets generated by $e^{-m t}$ to solve second problem as follows

```
UE[m_, t_] := Exp[-m t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 7; nn = 
 Total[With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
   Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]]; dx = 
 1/(nn); xl = Table[s*dx, {s, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[s - 1]] + xl[[s]])/2, {s, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Intx1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
 Intx2 = Integrate[Intx1 Sqrt[t1], t1, Assumptions -> t1 > 0]; 
intx1[y_] := Intx1 /. t1 -> y; intx2[y_] := Intx2 /. t1 -> y; 
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y;

xmin = 0; xmax = 100; l = xmax - xmin; x0 = 1; x1 = x0/l;
dAfFun[x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{1.4476805109594064` 10^-23 + 
     1.1735563659975857` 10^-24 x^(1.4), xmin <= x <= xmax}}, 0]
AfFun[x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{4.17425813460343` 10^-24 + 4.4423429301477025` 10^-23 x, 
    xmin <= x <= xmax}}, 0]
Rx1Fun[x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{4.537932520459608` 10^-17/(1 + 
         1.3188535755423771` Exp[-0.07679009872276484` (x - x0)]) - 
     4.529403364443408`*^-17/(1 + 
        1.3148412969171435` Exp[-0.07683234639209759` (x - x0)]), 
    x0 <= x <= xmax}}, 0]

a[x_] := dAfFun[x l] 10^20
b[x_] := AfFun[x l] 10^20
c1[x_] := Rx1Fun[x l] 10^20



var1 = Array[v, {nn}]; var2 = Array[u, {nn}]; 
intf[x_] := var1 . intx2[x] + 2/3 v0 x^(3/2); 
f[x_] := var1 . intx1[x] + v0; f1[x_] := var1 . Psi[x]; 
g1[x_] := var2 . Psi[x]; g[x_] := var2 . intx1[x] + u0;

(*eq={a[x] f'[x]+b[x] f[x]==g[x],D[g[x],x]+(c1[x+x1] f[x+x1]-c1[x] \
f[x])==0};bc1=f'[l]\[Equal]0;
bc2=f[l]\[Equal]0;*)
eq = 
 Join[Table[g1[x]/l + (c1[x + x1] f[x + x1] - c1[x] f[x]), {x, xcol}],
   Table[-g[x] + a[x] f1[x]/l + b[x] f[x], {x, xcol}]]; varM = 
 Join[var1, var2, {v0, u0}];  
eqs = Join[
  Table[eq[[i]] == 0, {i, 2, Length[eq] - 1}], {l^(3/2) intf[1] == 1, 
   f1[0] == 0, f[1] == 0, g[1] == 0}]; sol = 
 FindRoot[eqs, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]];
```

Visualization numerical solution and `PDF[ChiDistribution[1], x]`

```
{Plot[PDF[ChiDistribution[1], x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "PDF[ChiDistribution[1],x]"], 
 Plot[Evaluate[{f[x/l] /. sol}], {x, 0, 20}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> nn], 
 Plot[Evaluate[{f[x/l] /. sol}], {x, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> nn]}
```

[image: Figure 4]

Note, that we can solve linear system of equations with `LinearSolve` using

```
{vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqs, varM];

soll = LinearSolve[mat, -vec];

rule = Table[varM[[i]] -> soll[[i]], {i, Length[varM]}];
```

Visualization two numerical solutions

```
Plot[Evaluate[{f[x/l] /. rule, f[x/l] /. sol}], {x, 0, l}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> nn, 
 PlotLegends -> {"LinearSolve", "FindRoot"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}]
```

[image: Figure 5]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Alex. I will review it and let you know.

Comment: How did you choose the values for `k0` and `M0`? Both affect the solution pretty much.

Comment: It is why we need some theorem about method convergence for this equation. For pantograph type delay differential equations this method working well also with Haar wavelets - see, for instance,   https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1018364718312278?via%3Dihub

Comment: I can recommend to add some constraint like `f>0` at `0<x<l`.

Comment: Yes, that is reasonable in this problem. Shall I add it in `FindRoot`? Another question is about using `FindRoot`. Why not to use `NSolve`?

Comment: This problem is linear, therefore we can use `NSolve` and `LinearSolve` as well. But, even with `f>0` problem looks like unbounded for some combinations `k0, M0` when we solve it with  `NMinimize`. May be solution is not unique.

Comment: I will run it with `NSolve` and let you know.

Comment: What does `1/10` represent in `FindRoot`?

Comment: This is starting point for iterations. I have computed several runs with nn=10,16, 24, 28, 32, 56 and then combine in one plot. It looks like we need to restrict `f[0]` as well, for example, `f[0]==0` or `f[0]==1`.  See update 1 to my answer.

Comment: Actually, `f[0]` is unknown and is a very important parameter. On the other hand, we know that `f[0] = Max[f[x]]`, so, maybe `f'[0] == 0` could be helpful?

I have updated the OP with more appropriate expressions for `a`, `b` and `c1` coefficients. Could you lease have a look when you have time?

Comment: I have run the last update for multiple `UE` and various values of parameters. The solution seems to be unstable with respect to parameters.

I was thinking about implementing the RK method described in Section 6 of the following book. What would be your opinion?
 http://homepages.math.slu.cz/KarelHasik/Numerical%20Methods%20for%20Delay%20Differential%20Equations.pdf

Comment: It is not so differ from `NDSolve`. Use `eq = {h'[x] == Sqrt[x] f[x], 
  g'[x] + (c1[x + x1] f[x] - c1[x] f[x]) == 0, 
  a[x] f'[x] + b[x] f[x] == g[x]};` `bc = {g[l] == 0, f[l] == 0, h[l] == 1};`

`{F, G, H} = NDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, {f, g, h}, {x, 0, l}]`

Comment: Omitting `+ x1` in the argument of `f` changes the equation and the solution entirely. If `x0` would be small, we could use the approximation `f[x + x0] = f[x] + f'[x] x0 + 1/2 f''[x] x0^2` which works well, but `x0` is not always small...