# Numerical solution of an ordinary integro-differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

I am trying to solve the following integro-differential equation:
$$
a(\varepsilon) f'(\varepsilon) + b(\varepsilon) f(\varepsilon) + \int_{\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon + \varepsilon_1} R_1(\epsilon) f(\epsilon) d\epsilon - \int_{\varepsilon - \varepsilon_2}^{\varepsilon} R_2(\epsilon) f(\epsilon) d\epsilon = 0,
$$
where $\varepsilon_1 = 10$, $\varepsilon_2 = 20$.

Note that the reduction of this equation into a second-order ODE is possible, but is much harder to solve. See, e.g., [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268104/numerical-solution-of-an-advance-delay-ode-with-multiple-advances-and-delays).

Taking

```
eps1 = 10;
eps2 = 20;
epsmin = .025;
epsmax = 150;
a[eps_] := 1 + eps
b[eps_] := eps^1.4
R1[eps_] := Piecewise[{{eps, eps1 <= eps <= epsmax}}, 0]
R2[eps_] := Piecewise[{{eps, eps2 <= eps <= epsmax}}, 0]
```

We know that `f[eps] > 0` for `epsmin <= eps <= epsmax`, and that `f[eps] = 0` for `eps <= epsmin` and `eps >= epsmax`. For `eps >= epsmax`, all derivatives of `f[eps]` also become 0. Also,

```
Integrate[Sqrt[eps] f[eps], {eps, epsmin, epsmax}] == 1;
```

I have tried to use `NDSolve` with `NIntegrate` as follows:

```
solBW = NDSolve[{a[eps]f'[eps] + b[eps]f[eps] + NIntegrate[R1[y]f[y],{y,eps,eps + eps1}] - NIntegrate[R2[y]f[y],{y, eps - eps2, eps}] == 0, f[epsmax] == 0}, f, {eps, epsmax, epsmin}];
```

but it returns

```
NIntegrate: y = eps is not a valid limit of integration.
```

Any hint on how to solve this equation numerically is appreciated.

Comment: Differentiate your equation and solve for f'. Subsequently integrate f'.

Comment: The derivative of the integral terms will produce `f[eps + eps1]` and `f[eps - eps2]` terms. I can't proceed from that point.

Comment: Why not to use collocation method?

Comment: The term in your equation `1/a[eps] Integrate[R2[eps1] f[eps1], {eps1, eps - eps2, eps}]`  is in discordance with `eps1 = 10;` for Mathematica syntax. Upgrade your math culture.

Comment: @AlexTrounev as me and you verified, the collocation method gives negative solutions

Comment: @user64494 thank you pointing it out. I was using a simplified notation in the post. In the code they do not conflict. I just updated the post.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan It looks like it can be solved with FDM - see my answer.

Comment: Thanks @AlexTrounev, I am currently testing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like we can solve this problem with using FDM and `LinearSolve[]` as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

y1 = 10;
y2 = 20;
ymin = .025;
ymax = 150.025;
a[y_] := 1 + y;
b[y_] := y^1.4
R1[y_] := Piecewise[{{y, y1 <= y <= ymax}}, 0];
R2[y_] := Piecewise[{{y, y2 <= y <= ymax}}, 0];


h = 1/5; xcol = Range[ymin, ymax, h]; nn = Length[xcol]; u = 
 Array[f, {nn}];

eq = Join[
   Table[a[xcol[[j]]] 1/2 (f[j + 1] - f[j - 1])/h + 
      b[xcol[[j]]] f[j] + 
      h Sum[If[k <= Length[xcol], R1[xcol[[k]]] f[k], 0], {k, j, 
         j + Round[y1/h]}] - 
      h Sum[If[k >= 1, R2[xcol[[k]]] f[k], 0], {k, j - Round[y2/h], 
         j}] == 0, {j, 2, nn - 1}], {h Sqrt[xcol] . u == 1, 
    f[nn] == 0}];
{vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eq, u];

sol = LinearSolve[mat, -vec];
```

Visualization

```
{ListLinePlot[Table[{xcol[[i]], sol[[i]]}, {i, nn}], 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 ListLinePlot[Table[{xcol[[i]], sol[[i]]}, {i, Round[20/h]}], 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 ListLinePlot[Table[{xcol[[i]], sol[[i]]}, {i, Round[20/h] + 1, nn}], 
  PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Now if we turn step to `h=1/10`, then we have same picture, therefore numerical method is stable
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Sorry for being picky, but why the tail does not decrease to `10^-40` or lower? Both integral terms decrease pretty fast and so should `f`.

Comment: May be you need to increase `WorkingPrecision` up to 40 and decrease `h` to 1/30, also use rational inputs like  `ymin = 25/1000`.

Comment: I used `$PreRead = (#/.s_String/;StringMatchQ[s,NumberString]&&Precision@ToExpression@s == MachinePrecision :>s<>" 150."&)`
`ymin =Rationalize[ .025,0]` (same for `ymax`) and `h = 1/30`. No difference.

Comment: Please, use also `b[y_] := y^(14/10)` and `sol = LinearSolve[N[mat, 40], -vec];` to speed up computation. Decrease step to `h=1/40`. Check, that difference with `h=30` is minor. It means that solution converges.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex, your solution works very good. I have 2 questions:
1. Is there any way to accelerate it? When I add all the integral terms (10 terms in total), it runs the case `h = 1/10` in more than 1 minute.
2․ Apparently, the discretization plays a huge role. For instance, when `h = 1/5`, there are negative solutions and even for `h = 1/10`, there are regions with highly oscillating solutions (should not occur). Would that be possible to have a non-uniform grid with very dense points near `eps = 0` and distant points after that?

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan We can use dense grid with FEM, but dense grid is not  the only method to avoid oscillations. Also oscillations may by exited due to model instability and not as numerical solution instability.

Comment: I agree, but the physical interpretation of the problem suggests that there should no be instabilities in the model. Besides, when I run it for `h = 1/5`, there are intervals where `f` is negative. But for `h = 1/10`, negative solutions disappear and highly oscillating solutions occur. I think, this can be fixed for `h = 1/20`, but unfortunately, the computational time on Wolfram Cloud is limited to 1 minute, so I cannot test it.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan This question seems to be answered. Could you upload code with 10 terms in a new topic?